# How can i use Selenium WebDriver to open chrome new tab window in the background?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, selenium, selenium-webdriver

If i'm using just Process Start it will open a new browser chrome window but will focus on the window.
I want to open a new chrome tab but without focus on it the tab will be on the background behind the current window i'm in now.

Only if i click on the browser icon i will see the opened tab and can click on the tab to focus on it.

In Form1 top i did:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
```

Constructor:

```
OpenBroswerTab();
```

And

```
private void OpenBroswerTab()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/");

            IWebElement body = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
            body.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control.ToString() + 't');

            //driver.Quit();
        }
```

But also with this code i still see the opened new tab/window of the chrome.
The new opened tab/window should be minimized opened in the background so i will not see it open.

Comment: Not sure if you can hide it or not, but If you don't actually need Chrome for your tests, you could look at PhantomJS Driver which will do everything in a Console window and there is an option to hide that.

Comment: @TyCobb He doesn't need to hide browser. He needs Chrome running in background and not stealing focus from other applications when new tab opens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window handles to control the tabs:

If you have a tab open and you open another one, you can immediately call this to return to the previously open tab.  If you have many tabs open and just want to get back to the first one you should be able to replace the "myDriver.WindowHandles.Count -1" with simply "0".

```
ChromeDriver myDriver = new ChromeDriver();
myDriver.SwitchTo().Window(myDriver.WindowHandles[myDriver.WindowHandles.Count - 1]);
```